# Sails.js - Expecting HTML, getting JSON

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to institute a user profile page. When a user signs in, I want them directed to their "profile" page. I have been following the sailscasts for ActivityOverload1.0 found here:

http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/11/20/sailscasts-answers-ep4-creating-a-more-attractive-url-in-sails-with-slugs-dot-dot-dot-really/

After following the tutorial, I can now browse to localhost:1337/user/santaclause however I get the following json output as opposed to getting html.

```
{
  "path": "C:\\sails\\whatever\\views\\user\\profile.ejs"
}
```

UserController:

```
profile: function (req, res, next) {
var username = req.param('username');

if (username.match(/\..+$/)) return next();

User.findOneByUsername(username)
.exec(function (err, user){
  if (err) return res.serverError(err);
  if (!user) return next();
  res.view({user: user});
});
```

},

profile.ejs

https://gist.github.com/CiscoKidxx/a6c235e96fb3cb87f90d

I also see a `GET /santaclause 500` error with verbose logging on the console.

What do you think I am doing wrong?

I am inclined to think it is something with my profile.ejs file.. for no good reason.

Comment: Could you share your console error?

Comment: The only error is the one in the OP... GET /santaclause 500

Comment: I have logging set to "silly"

Comment: And your `profile.ejs`? Can you share that?

Comment: Added gist link to profile.ejs

Comment: Did you make sure that the partials you include are there and there is no typo in their paths?

Comment: Yeah paths are good. Before correcting, they were wrong and the error indicated it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79882/discussion-between-robertignat-and-djangodummy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look into the code... I found that the problem was in `views/partials/private/nav.ejs` on line 21:

```
<a style="color: #3396BF"><%= me.email %></a>
```

Should be:

```
<a style="color: #3396BF"><%= user.email %></a>
```

Comment: Right you are! Thanks for all of your help.